# QuickFIX/J is removing tags from FIX message

Tags: quickfix, quickfixj

Is it possible for **QuickFIX/J** to remove some tags of the incoming FIX message? If yes, why would it be like that?
The problem is when receiving **35=X (MarketDataIncrementalRefresh)** message. The message comes from the server, and has the corresponding tangs, including the tags **48 SecurityID** and **22 SecurityIDSource** and the checksum is the correct one, calculated including those 2 fields. When processing the message in the client, the message does no longer contain the 48 and 22 tags and the checksum is also different. Because of those 2 missing tags, that are required, the client cannot process the message. I couldn't trace the cause of this. (The data dictionary contains the tags 22 and 48 and are marked as required).

The session config:

```
[session]
BeginString=FIXT.1.1
SocketConnectPort=9122
UseDataDictionary=Y
AllowUnknownMsgFields=Y
ValidateFieldsOutOfOrder=N
ValidateUnorderedGroupFields=N
ValidateIncomingMessage=N
TransportDataDictionary=transport_dict_FIXT11.xml
AppDataDictionary=data_dict_FIX44.xml
SocketUseSSL=Y
EnabledProtocols=TLSv1.2
SocketKeyStore=file.jks
SocketKeyStorePassword=password
```

Example of message from log:

```
Failed to process 8=FIXT.1.1|9=145|35=X|34=226|49=SenderCompID|52=20201202-13:42:34.345|56=TargetCompID|262=EU000A1U99281083|268=1|279=0|264=1|269=0|278=EU000A1U9928_BID_1|110=1000|10=217:
quickfix.FieldNotFound: Field [48] was not found in message.
```

Comment: Are there unknown fields after tags 22 and 48 in the message? Normally this behaviour can be seen on unknown tags in repeating groups and disabled validation. Can you share your session config and an example message?

Comment: No, there aren't any unknown fields. Yes, I will add in the post the message and the session config.

Comment: Can you also add the original message before the tags are removed?

Comment: Thank you for your interest in this, I managed to found the problem. It was because of the dictionary used for data, FIX44 instead of FIXT11. The provider resets the DefaultApplVerID to FIXT11 after logon, even if our logon request has DefaultApplVerID set to FIX44.

Comment: Good that you found it. You could add that as an answer.